# Вывод возможных ходов слона на шахматной доске при столкновении с дружественной фигурой

Tags: python, шахматы

Пишу программу, которая отображает координаты возможных ходов двух фигур, в данном случае слонов, на шахматной доске. Если фигура **B** стоит на пути фигуры **А**, список возможных ходов фигуры **А** не будет содержать координату, на которой стоит фигура **В** и все координаты за фигурой **В** .

```
def positions_for_two_bishop():
print('Enter first figure position\n')
while True:
    v1 = input('Enter vertical position (A-H): ')
    if ord(v1) in range(ord('a'), ord('h') + 1):
        break

while True:
    h1 = int(input('Enter horizontal position (1-8): '))
    if h1 in range(1, 9):
        break

print('Enter second figure position\n')
while True:
    v2 = input('Enter vertical position (A-H): ')
    if ord(v2) in range(ord('a'), ord('h') + 1):
        break

while True:
    h2 = int(input('Enter horizontal position (1-8): '))
    if h2 in range(1, 9):
        break

for i in range(ord('a'), ord('h') + 1):
    for j in range(1, 9):
        if( ( abs( i - ord(v1) ) == abs( j - h1 ) ) and ( i != ord(v1) or j != h1 ) ):
            if ( i != ord(v2) and j != h2 ):
                move = chr(i) + str(j)
                moves.append(move)
print(f'B on {v1 + str(h1)}: {moves}')
```

При выполнении данного кода координаты клетки, на которой стоит вторая фигура, не выводятся. Но программа считает клетки за второй фигурой за возможные ходы, так как цикл проходит по этим координатам раньше, чем встречает клетку, на которой стоит вторая фигура.

Comment: *При выполнении данного кода координаты клетки, на которой стоит вторая фигура, не выводятся.* Ну так в этот момент надо просто прерывать цикл по этой диагонали в этом направлении. А для этого плясать надо не по диагонали от начала до конца, плюя, где стоит фигура, а именно от неё, и во всех 4 направлениях.

Comment: @Akina, да, точно, спасибо)

Может глупый вопрос, но как я понял, нужен вложенный цикл, в котором будет поочередно меняться знак, а как лучше это реализовать?